# How to print out a specific array and return its pointer from a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I asked a question here before the answer to which i found it myself. But there was an extra requirement.

The exercise goes like this :

We are given an array of float values of size N. Each float value represents a cash flow in a bank account. For example a deposit (when the value is positive) or a withdrawal (when it is negative). The initial balance of the account is equal to zero.

So if the cash flow is `(+10, -5, +7, -8)` the balances are `(0+10)=+10`, `(10-5)=+5`, `(5+7)=+12`, and `(12-8)=+4`; thus the maximum and minimum balances
are +12 and +4, with a difference equal to +8

with the same set of cash flows but ordered as `(-5, +10, -8, +7)` the balances are`(0-5)=-5`, `(-5+10)=+5`, `(+5-8)=-3`, and `(-3+7)=+4`, with a maximum and a minimum equal to +5 and -5 and a difference is equal to +10.

Using recursion we have to find the best arrangement so that the difference between the maximum and minimum is minimal

This is the code that prints out every permutation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void permutation(float *val,float *sol,float *mark,int n,int pos)
{
    if(pos==n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%.0f ",sol[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(mark[i]==0)
        {
            mark[i]=1;
            sol[pos]=val[i];
            permutation(val,sol,mark,n,pos+1);
            mark[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    float *sol;
    float *val;
    int n=4;
    float *mark;
    mark = calloc(n, sizeof(float ));
    if(mark==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    val = malloc(n* sizeof(float ));
    if(val==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    val=(float []){+10, -5, +7, -8};
    
    sol=malloc(n* sizeof(float));
    if(sol==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    permutation(val,sol,mark,n,0);
    return 0;
}
```

But as i said how do i print out a specific array in my case the one that the difference between max and min is minimal. Also the exercise requires me to return the pointer of this array. How do i do that as well?

Comment: Tip: Collapse your variable definition and initial assignment to the same line, like `int x = 0` and `float *mark = calloc(...)` as this helps ensure everything is initialized properly and as a bonus, minimizes how much time we need to spend tracking down what type each variable is.

Comment: With code like `val=(float []){+10, -5, +7, -8}` I do wonder if maybe you don't actually need a dynamically allocated value here.

Comment: Also for trivial programs like this where you're not memory constrained, you can ditch the `if (x == NULL)` checks because they won't happen. Small allocations will succeed unless your computer is at the absolute limit of what it can allocate, in which case it'll be absolutely sluggish and borderline unusable due to swapping.

Comment: @tadman as for the last one is more like for practice as to say. Most of the time I know memory allocation will work but it doesn't hurt to do a check. As for why I initialize the array after I allocate it it's because the exercise requires we pass a pointer array but I also needed it initialized.

Comment: @tadman plus these are exam exercises that I'm trying to do and the professors usually want to check everything.

Comment: You can pass a pointer to an array that's on the stack. Pretty much anything in C can be a pointer if you want it to be.

Comment: I get that professors can be jerks, so you need to stick to the rules there. It's just that here stuff like that clutters up your question with basically useless junk so it's best to omit it. Each allocation has four lines of whatever after it which makes an otherwise compact block of code turn into this huge thing that now needs to scroll.

Comment: @tadman well. Nothing I can do. And to be fair I've done it so many times it basically feels uncomfortable to not do it xd

Comment: Why not write a custom sort function and use that to sort these permutations from best to worst? You could also use that comparator function to find the "max" in the array doing a linear scan. Either way is fine.

Comment: You can omit it from questions on Stack Overflow where clutter like that impedes readability. You can do whatever you have to do in your actual version.

Comment: @tadman I thought about using a max and min and saving them to find the minimum difference. How do I know that the current best min diff I've found is the best one overall. Yes for the moment for example I can say that this works but I may be able to find a better solution after idk many more iterations. It's why I asked the question in the first place. How do I print out the specific array I'm looking for.

Comment: A) Write a print function for a generic array. B) Write a comparator function between two arrays. C) Use sort or a max-finder function that returns a pointer to the max array.

Comment: @tadman all right I'll think on this for a bit but currently it's 7am over here and I haven't slept all night. Still thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is that, instead of printing during the recursion, perform your calculations on each permutation. If it yields the best result yet, copy the current permutation to an output buffer.

Once all permutations are exhausted, then you print the best one.

Note that in the event where two or more permutations produce the best result, this chooses the first encountered. This means the starting order of the array influences the order of the result.

A cursory, naive example using your algorithm (and [VLAs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays)):

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_array(float *data, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%5.1f ", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

static float flow_minmax_diff(float *data, size_t length)
{
    float min = FLT_MAX;
    float max = FLT_MIN;
    float balance = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        balance += data[i];

        if (balance > max)
            max = balance;

        if (balance < min)
            min = balance;
    }

    return max - min;
}

static void permutation_actual(
        float *difference,
        float *result,
        float *values,
        float *swap,
        bool *marked,
        size_t length,
        size_t depth)
{
    if (depth == length) {
        float d = flow_minmax_diff(swap, length);

        if (d < *difference) {
            *difference = d;
            memcpy(result, swap, sizeof *swap * length);
        }

        return;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (marked[i])
            continue;

        marked[i] = true;
        swap[depth] = values[i];
        permutation_actual(difference, result, values, swap, marked, length, depth + 1);
        marked[i] = false;
    }
}

static float best_permutation(float *res, float *values, size_t length)
{
    float temp[length];
    bool markers[length];
    memset(markers, 0, sizeof markers);

    float diff = FLT_MAX;
    permutation_actual(&diff, res, values, temp, markers, length, 0);
    return diff;
}

int main(void)
{
    float values[] = { -8.f, -5.f, 7.f, 10.f };
    size_t length = sizeof values / sizeof *values;
    float best[length];
    float difference = best_permutation(best, values, length);

    printf("Difference: %5.1f\n", difference);
    print_array(best, length);
}
```

Result:

```
Difference:   8.0
 10.0  -8.0   7.0  -5.0
```

As for how to *"return the pointer of this array"*, with the example in mind, you could simply allocate (`malloc`) the resulting array in `best_permutation`, and return it, instead of feeding it as an argument.

*(`flow_minmax_diff` could always be called on the result.)*

---

As a side note, this

```
val = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
val = (float []){ +10, -5, +7, -8 };
```

is two very separate assignments of a `float *` value to the variable `val`. This does **not** perform any kind of "initialization" of the memory located at the address returned by `malloc`.

The result being that `val` is a pointer to the first element of [an array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) of [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration), and the memory allocated by `malloc` is leaked.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float *val = malloc(4 * sizeof(float));
    printf("%p\n", (void *) val);
    val = (float []){ +10, -5, +7, -8 };
    printf("%p\n", (void *) val);
}
```

```
0x55bd9c5092a0
0x7ffd138ea010
```

Comment: Thanks! Im going to need a bit of time to "translate " this in my own code but thanks a lot